# ansible access items from register variable

Tags: json, list, variables, ansible

I run a task that captures the status of an interface for multiple devices and in some cases for more than one interface but I can only retrieve one stdout_lines at a time but I need to retrieve all of the stdout_lines for the hosts it runs the command on.  I have the task code to access a respective stdout_lines of the list but not all of them.

```
    - name: Execute IOS command to check port state up/down before configuration
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - "show ip int brief | in {{item}}"
      loop: "{{ports}}"
      register: PortUpDown

    - name: print port state up/down
      debug:
        #msg: "{{item.0 | to_nice_yaml}}"
        #msg: "{{item.1 | to_nice_yaml}}"
        msg: "{{item}}"
      loop:
        #- "{{PortUpDown.results.0.stdout_lines}}"
        #- "{{PortUpDown.results.1.stdout_lines}}"
         - "{{PortUpDown.results}}"
      register: PortUpDown

    - name: print var that capture port state up/down
      debug:
        var: PortUpDown
```

As you can see I have commented the items I was accessing during the testing. What I ultimately want is to be able to access 0,1,2,3 etc without the need to declare it because at the start of the script I will not know if it's just going to be one interface or multiple interfaces in the list that I'm going to get the port state.

The output is this.

```
    ok: [hub1] => {
    "PortUpDown": {
        "changed": false, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                "changed": false, 
                "failed": false, 
                "item": [
                    {
                        "ansible_facts": {
                            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
                        }, 
                        "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "failed": false, 
                        "invocation": {
                            "module_args": {
                                "auth_pass": null, 
                                "authorize": null, 
                                "commands": [
                                    "show ip int brief | in Ethernet1/1"
                                ], 
                                "host": null, 
                                "interval": 1, 
                                "match": "all", 
                                "password": null, 
                                "port": null, 
                                "provider": null, 
                                "retries": 10, 
                                "ssh_keyfile": null, 
                                "timeout": null, 
                                "username": null, 
                                "wait_for": null
                            }
                        }, 
                        "item": "Ethernet1/1", 
                        "stdout": [
                            "Ethernet1/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up"
                        ], 
                        "stdout_lines": [
                            [
                                "Ethernet1/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "failed": false, 
                        "invocation": {
                            "module_args": {
                                "auth_pass": null, 
                                "authorize": null, 
                                "commands": [
                                    "show ip int brief | in Ethernet2/1"
                                ], 
                                "host": null, 
                                "interval": 1, 
                                "match": "all", 
                                "password": null, 
                                "port": null, 
                                "provider": null, 
                                "retries": 10, 
                                "ssh_keyfile": null, 
                                "timeout": null, 
                                "username": null, 
                                "wait_for": null
                            }
                        }, 
                        "item": "Ethernet2/1", 
                        "stdout": [
                            "Ethernet2/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down"
                        ], 
                        "stdout_lines": [
                            [
                                "Ethernet2/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                ], 
                "msg": [
                    {
                        "ansible_facts": {
                            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
                        }, 
                        "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "failed": false, 
                        "invocation": {
                            "module_args": {
                                "auth_pass": null, 
                                "authorize": null, 
                                "commands": [
                                    "show ip int brief | in Ethernet1/1"
                                ], 
                                "host": null, 
                                "interval": 1, 
                                "match": "all", 
                                "password": null, 
                                "port": null, 
                                "provider": null, 
                                "retries": 10, 
                                "ssh_keyfile": null, 
                                "timeout": null, 
                                "username": null, 
                                "wait_for": null
                            }
                        }, 
                        "item": "Ethernet1/1", 
                        "stdout": [
                            "Ethernet1/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up"
                        ], 
                        "stdout_lines": [
                            [
                                "Ethernet1/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "failed": false, 
                        "invocation": {
                            "module_args": {
                                "auth_pass": null, 
                                "authorize": null, 
                                "commands": [
                                    "show ip int brief | in Ethernet2/1"
                                ], 
                                "host": null, 
                                "interval": 1, 
                                "match": "all", 
                                "password": null, 
                                "port": null, 
                                "provider": null, 
                                "retries": 10, 
                                "ssh_keyfile": null, 
                                "timeout": null, 
                                "username": null, 
                                "wait_for": null
                            }
                        }, 
                        "item": "Ethernet2/1", 
                        "stdout": [
                            "Ethernet2/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down"
                        ], 
                        "stdout_lines": [
                            [
                                "Ethernet2/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
ok: [hub2] => {
    "PortUpDown": {
        "changed": false, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                "changed": false, 
                "failed": false, 
                "item": [
                    {
                        "ansible_facts": {
                            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
                        }, 
                        "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "failed": false, 
                        "invocation": {
                            "module_args": {
                                "auth_pass": null, 
                                "authorize": null, 
                                "commands": [
                                    "show ip int brief | in Ethernet1/1"
                                ], 
                                "host": null, 
                                "interval": 1, 
                                "match": "all", 
                                "password": null, 
                                "port": null, 
                                "provider": null, 
                                "retries": 10, 
                                "ssh_keyfile": null, 
                                "timeout": null, 
                                "username": null, 
                                "wait_for": null
                            }
                        }, 
                        "item": "Ethernet1/1", 
                        "stdout": [
                            "Ethernet1/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up"
                        ], 
                        "stdout_lines": [
                            [
                                "Ethernet1/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "failed": false, 
                        "invocation": {
                            "module_args": {
                                "auth_pass": null, 
                                "authorize": null, 
                                "commands": [
                                    "show ip int brief | in Ethernet2/1"
                                ], 
                                "host": null, 
                                "interval": 1, 
                                "match": "all", 
                                "password": null, 
                                "port": null, 
                                "provider": null, 
                                "retries": 10, 
                                "ssh_keyfile": null, 
                                "timeout": null, 
                                "username": null, 
                                "wait_for": null
                            }
                        }, 
                        "item": "Ethernet2/1", 
                        "stdout": [
                            "Ethernet2/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down"
                        ], 
                        "stdout_lines": [
                            [
                                "Ethernet2/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                ], 
                "msg": [
                    {
                        "ansible_facts": {
                            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
                        }, 
                        "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "failed": false, 
                        "invocation": {
                            "module_args": {
                                "auth_pass": null, 
                                "authorize": null, 
                                "commands": [
                                    "show ip int brief | in Ethernet1/1"
                                ], 
                                "host": null, 
                                "interval": 1, 
                                "match": "all", 
                                "password": null, 
                                "port": null, 
                                "provider": null, 
                                "retries": 10, 
                                "ssh_keyfile": null, 
                                "timeout": null, 
                                "username": null, 
                                "wait_for": null
                            }
                        }, 
                        "item": "Ethernet1/1", 
                        "stdout": [
                            "Ethernet1/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up"
                        ], 
                        "stdout_lines": [
                            [
                                "Ethernet1/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                        "changed": false, 
                        "failed": false, 
                        "invocation": {
                            "module_args": {
                                "auth_pass": null, 
                                "authorize": null, 
                                "commands": [
                                    "show ip int brief | in Ethernet2/1"
                                ], 
                                "host": null, 
                                "interval": 1, 
                                "match": "all", 
                                "password": null, 
                                "port": null, 
                                "provider": null, 
                                "retries": 10, 
                                "ssh_keyfile": null, 
                                "timeout": null, 
                                "username": null, 
                                "wait_for": null
                            }
                        }, 
                        "item": "Ethernet2/1", 
                        "stdout": [
                            "Ethernet2/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down"
                        ], 
                        "stdout_lines": [
                            [
                                "Ethernet2/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of the filter [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#map) to extract the `stdout_lines` of all the elements of your list and then [`flatten`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-list-variables) the resulting list of list in order to do this.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - command: "echo {{ item }}"
      loop: 
        - "Ethernet2/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down"
        - "Ethernet1/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up"
      register: PortUpDown

    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ PortUpDown.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | list | flatten }}"
```

This yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************************************************

TASK [command] *****************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=Ethernet2/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down)
changed: [localhost] => (item=Ethernet1/1                unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up)

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=Ethernet2/1 unassigned YES NVRAM administratively down down) => {
    "msg": "Ethernet2/1 unassigned YES NVRAM administratively down down"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Ethernet1/1 unassigned YES NVRAM up up) => {
    "msg": "Ethernet1/1 unassigned YES NVRAM up up"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: quick question on this. What section in ansible doc can I read more about it so I can fully understand what is going on?

Comment: Sorry I don't fully get your question? What do you mean by _what is going on_?

Comment: Oh I meant to say if there is any documentation that I can read up on that goes over handling variables with maps and passing the filters.

Comment: What you might want to read first is [Jinja's documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/), since Jinja is the templating system used by Ansible. The page might seems long at first sight, but realy, it is not that long, especially if you know that you have the **whole** documentation on that page. Ansible have a set of extra filters added to Jinja and all those are grouped on [a single page of the Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) too.

Comment: With all this you should have a faire enough overview, as far as templating in Ansible is concerned.